# How to create a shapefile of circles from geo coordinates and radius in meters and project it correctly?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap

I have latitude and longitude coordinates for India from Google Maps in degrees and radius in meters as displayed below:
[image]

I want to create a shapefile of circles with given radius. I know about Analysis - Buffer tool, my problem is mostly about projection because the circles look very large, though the radius is half kilometer only. I don't know which projection to use to display the BUFF_DIST in meters and correctly display my data.

I tried Indian_1975_UTM_Zone_48N and the circle covers the whole India. I guess the problem is whether it assumes the radius in meters or km.

How can I project correctly Indian coordinates? I am using ArcMap 10.4.1

Comment: Your coordinates are WGS84 aka EPSG:4326. This uses degree as unit. Buffers are created using the layers CRS - hence you need to save your data to a m-based CRS and then create the buffers.

Comment: I've never had an issue generating geodetic buffers with ArcGIS.  I'm pretty sure you just need to specify the units correctly.

Comment: I changed the projection of XY data and the data frame to WGS_1984_World_Mercator and now Buffer works. I think now the BUFF_DIST is correctly displayed in meters because circles are small. Thank you very much!

Comment: You pretty much ***never*** want to use Web Mercator for distance calculation (it's ***always*** wrong).

Comment: And which projection to use? I checked some distances in Google maps and the error is about 30-40 km.